# Как убрать блокировку строчки в бд?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Использую Sql-server столкнулся с проблемой блокировок записи.
Есть 2 таблицы: MainTable и SubTable. У MainTable стоит триггер, что приобновлении записи в MainTable обновляется и некоторая строчка в SubTable. И есть некоторый запрос который который обновляет только строчки только в SubTable.

Есть 2 кейса:

1. Когда происходит одновременно запросы, хотелось бы получить. Чтобы данные с триггера сохранились, а обновление от запроса, было либо потерено, либо подождало, но не блокировалось.
2. Получение данных (select * from SubTable) не получить данные, если в данный момент с ними идет работа

По второму варианту как я понял, запрос должен выглядеть: (select * from SubTable with (UPDLOCK, ROWLOCK, READPAST))
А вот с первым кейсом, не понимаю, как настроить триггер

Так выглядит триггер:

```
    Create trigger Update_MainTable on MainTable after 
UPDATE  as 
begin
Update SubTable with(ROWLOCK) set [LatUpdateTime] = SYSDATETIME() 
where SubTable.[ClientTableId] in (select Id from inserted) and [Table] = 'MainTable'
end;
```

Comment: либо подождало, но не блокировалось - "подождало" - это и есть "блокировалось". Вам нужно ожидание? или падение с ошибкой?. по второму пункту - включите на базе read committed snapshot (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server), тогда селект не будет блокироваться, а будет вычитывать старые данные

Comment: @PashaPash, Падение, тоже подойдет

Comment: Ну сейчас у вас должно быть ожидание - так что тоже должно подойти

Comment: @PashaPash, Мне надо либо ожидание только с одной стороны, со стороны запроса, либо падение с любой стороны. Для падения, как я понимаю, можно просто прописать, чтобы работал только со свободными данными?

Comment: @PashaPash, Можно же сделать, если более приоритетная транзакция с этими же данными, то первую транзакцию отменяем(удаляем, выкидываем с ошибкой)?

Comment: У транзакций нет приоритета. Максимум - можно уронить более позднюю транзакцию указанием nowait.

Comment: @PashaPash а SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY или он так себе работает?

Comment: @chilo5432, так у вас deadlock, или ожидание? Если нет deadlock-а, то от DEADLOCK_PRIORITY ни жарко, ни холодно. В вашем случае, насколько я понял его нет, а есть простое ожидание. Или вы получаете ошибки типа *"... bla-bla-bla **deadlock victim** bla-bla..."*?

Comment: @i-one. Ожидание, уже лучше сделать. И разобарлся, но возник другая проблема. Если включаю, данный триггер (добавил в код). Когда пытаюсь из первой транзакции обновить запись 1. А из второй транзакции, запись 2. То пока я не закомменчу, то запись вторая не обновить. В чем может быть дело?

Comment: @chilo5432 Сложно сказать, не имея всех деталей. Но, например, если MainTable обновляется в SERIALIZABLE транзакции, то и триггер будет выполняться с этим уровнем изоляции. Если на SubTable нет подходящего индекса для блокировки диапазона строк (здесь это INDEX([Table], ClientTableId)), то execution engine, - чтобы обеспечить сериализуемость, - может, например, проигнорировать rowlock и заблокировать всю таблицу. Соответственно одна транзакция будет ждать завершения другой (даже если данные фактически не пересекаются).

Comment: @i-one Решил проблему. С помощью строчки SET NOCOUNT ON в триггере